# hyperbolic motion: why picking a sign?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity

I'm studying hyperbolic motions, the metric is $(+,-,-,-)$. We assume motion just in one direction so 4-velocity and 4-acceleration are respectively

$$ u^\mu=(u^0,u^1,0,0) \\ w^\mu=(w^0,w^1,0,0)$$

With $w_\mu w^\mu = -g^2$

Now using the properties $u_\mu w^\mu = 0$ and $u_\mu u^\mu=1$ we arrive at $$(w^1)^2= \pm \sqrt{gu^0}$$.

In my notes we pick a sign, and we pick the plus sign. Here my confusion arises: if you pick the minus sign it leads you to the same exact differential equation that determines the hyperbolic motion so there's no difference between which sign you pick, the choice is basically irrelevant. But why do we have to make this choice and pick a sign, if we carry both signs everything would be redundant cause we have to solve the same equations twice, but what's wrong with that?